# How to force wrap on table entries

Tags: xml, xslt, pdf, xsl-fo

I'm having an issue where when I publish my modspecs to pdf (XSL-FO).  My tables are having issues, where the content of a cell will overflow its column into the next one.  How do I force a break on the text so that a new line is created instead?

I can't manually insert zero-space characters since the table entries are programmatically entered.  I'm looking for a simple solution that I can just simply add to docbook_pdf.xsl (either as a xsl:param or xsl:attribute)

**EDIT:**
Here is where I'm at currently:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0" xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format">
<xsl:import href="urn:docbkx:stylesheet"/>
...(the beginning of my stylesheet for pdf generation, e.g. header and footer content stuff)
<xsl:template match="text()">
    <xsl:call-template name="intersperse-with-zero-spaces">
        <xsl:with-param name="str" select="."/>
    </xsl:call-template>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template name="intersperse-with-zero-spaces">
    <xsl:param name="str"/>
    <xsl:variable name="spacechars">
        &#x9;&#xA;
        &#x2000;&#x2001;&#x2002;&#x2003;&#x2004;&#x2005;
        &#x2006;&#x2007;&#x2008;&#x2009;&#x200A;&#x200B;
    </xsl:variable>

    <xsl:if test="string-length($str) &gt; 0">
        <xsl:variable name="c1" select="substring($str, 1, 1)"/>
        <xsl:variable name="c2" select="substring($str, 2, 1)"/>

        <xsl:value-of select="$c1"/>
        <xsl:if test="$c2 != '' and
            not(contains($spacechars, $c1) or
            contains($spacechars, $c2))">
            <xsl:text>&#x200B;</xsl:text>
        </xsl:if>

        <xsl:call-template name="intersperse-with-zero-spaces">
            <xsl:with-param name="str" select="substring($str, 2)"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

With this, the long words are successfully broken up in the table cells! Unfortunately, the side effect is that normal text elsewhere (like in a  under sextion X) now breaks up words so that they appear on seperate lines.  Is there a way to isolate the above process to just tables?

Comment: This looks more like a XSL-FO vocabulary question. I've retagged as such. If you think is an XSLT question, please provide input sample and desired output.

Comment: @Alejandro:  Yes its technically an XSL-FO issue (since the problem doesn't exit in html).  I guess I'm hoping for a way to add something to the xml.

Comment: Do you want an XSLT solution that will put zero-space characters into the text? If so, can you provide the smallest possible example of your XSL-FO and what text/where you need to be made splittable?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

In the long words, try inserting a [zero-width space character](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-width_space) between the characters where a break is allowed.

- You can use XSLT to insert a zero-width space between every character. Here is one way to do it: http://groups.yahoo.com/neo/groups/XSL-FO/conversations/topics/1177.
- Here is a mailing list thread where various approaches to the problem are discussed: http://www.stylusstudio.com/xsllist/200201/post80920.html.
- The [SourceForge DocBook stylesheets](http://sourceforge.net/projects/docbook/) includes a template for breaking up long URLs in FO output; see http://www.sagehill.net/docbookxsl/Ulinks.html#BreakLongUrls. The template (`hyphenate-url`) is in [xref.xsl](http://docbook.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/docbook/trunk/xsl/fo/xref.xsl).

Comment: @mzjin: Can't manually add that character, since the column width is unknown, and the entry itself is generated at runtime

Comment: @mzjin: I'm using solution 1 and I've gotten very close, see the edit to my answer.

Comment: You should make sure that the template applies only to table cells. Try `<xsl:template match="entry/text()">`.

Comment: @mzjin: is it because we're missing a `<xsl:template match="@*|node()">` ?

Comment: @Ace, it could be a context problem. Try this: `<xsl:template match="text()[parent::entry]">`.

Comment: @mzjin: Nope, no luck with that :(

Comment: If you are using the DocBook 5 stylesheets, then you probably need to use `<xsl:template match="text()[parent::d:entry]">`. See http://www.sagehill.net/docbookxsl/ProcesingDb5.html#Db5Xslt. If this does not help, then you need to provide more details about your XML and XSLT setup.

Comment: @mzjin: Nope, that creates an error, saying it doesn't understand the prefix.  I've added the config stuff of my stylesheet on to my answer

Comment: OK, then you need to declare the prefix in your customization. See http://www.sagehill.net/docbookxsl/CustomDb5Xsl.html. But this only applies if you actually *are* using the Docbook 5 (namespace-aware stylesheets).

Comment: @mzjin: YES!  This is so close.  Now the normal text is left alone, and the tables are the only place that the breaks are being put!  But I just noticed that some of my table entries include a `<para>` element.  Is there a way I can exclude those?

Comment: Do you want to adjust text also if it is in a para in an entry? Then try `<xsl:template match="text()[ancestor::d:entry]">`.

Comment: @mzjin: What I mean is that i want the template applied to all `<Entry>` except where the entry contains a `<para>`

Comment: `<xsl:template match="text()[ancestor::d:entry and not(parent::d:para)]">`

Comment: @mzjin:Yes, perfect. The question has been answered to the fullest, though I'm curious about one last thing...Is there a way to modify the code above so that every 13 consectutive characters, if there is no space ' ', then add a zero-space character?

Answer (score 5):

Since you're using XSLT 2.0:

```
<xsl:template match="text()">
  <xsl:value-of
      select="replace(replace(., '(\P{Zs})(\P{Zs})', '$1&#x200B;$2'),
                      '([^\p{Zs}&#x200B;])([^\p{Zs}&#x200B;])',
                      '$1&#x200B;$2')" />
</xsl:template>
```

This is using category escapes (http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-2/#nt-catEsc) rather than an explicit list of characters to match, but you could do it that way instead.  It needs two `replace()` because the inner `replace()` can only insert the character between every second character.  The outer `replace()` matches on characters that are not either space characters or the character added by the inner `replace()`.

---

Inserting after every thirteenth non-space character:

```
<xsl:template match="text()">
  <xsl:value-of
      select="replace(replace(., '(\P{Zs}{13})', '$1&#x200B;'),
                      '&#x200B;(\p{Zs})',
                      '$1')" />
</xsl:template>
```

The inner `replace()` inserts the character after every 13 non-space characters, and the outer `replace()` fixes it if the 14th character was a space character.

---

If you are using AH Formatter, then you can use `axf:word-break="break-all"` to allow AH Formatter to break anywhere within a word.  See https://www.antenna.co.jp/AHF/help/en/ahf-ext.html#axf.word-break.