# XSL Where to Hyphenate words

Tags: xslt, xsl-fo

I have a lot of numbers in a table that are hyphenated.
But when there is a number containing a "/" character, I want to hyphenate after that... if it is necessary.

Is there a attribute for this?

XML Example:

```
<ptxt>123567/89012345</ptxt>
```

Split after "/" if necessary.

Thanks!

Comment: Im generating XSL-FO (then Antenna House to PDF).

Comment: Does Antenna House have any kind of configuration for hyphenation?

Comment: Did you consider inserting unicode soft hyphen characters? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soft_hyphen

Comment: Antenna House can read a custom xml file, and there you can specify all the words you want to be hyphenate in a special way; for example you can write "long-word", so the word "longword" will be hyphen after "long" and before "word" if necessary.

Comment: But I dont want to add every number in the hyphenation-xml-file. :P

Comment: @grtjn: I can not edit the xml-file, I want to automatise the PDF creation procedure. Thanks anyway!

Comment: @user1065283, I guess that this actually is a line wrapping issue rather than a hyphenation issue. Hyphenation is supposed to be applied to real words, and that is not what you have. See this answer for some suggestions: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4533760/407651.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a word joiner character (`&#8288;`) before your `/`. One way of doing this with XSLT could be :

```
<xsl:variable name="test" select="'123/456'"/>
<xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="contains($test,'/')">
        <xsl:value-of select="concat(substring-before($test,'/'),
            '&#8288;','/',substring-after($test,'/'))"/>
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:value-of select="$test"/>
    </xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
```

Answer (score 0):

A shorter way is:
    `<xsl:copy-of select="replace($test,'/','&#8288;/')"/>`