# How to wrap long lines withoud spaces in XSL:FO

Tags: xml, xsl-fo

If i got a very long word in my table, the text will continue through the border untill the next space or newline will come. Is there a way to wrap a string which is to long at the end of the column?

Comment: Duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4350788/xsl-fo-force-wrap-on-table-entries