# Wrap within table-cell with long word like email

Tags: word-wrap, xsl-fo, apache-fop, xmltable

Hi I am trying to wrap the long word like email within the cell but am unable to do the same, I have tried multiple options like wrap-option="wrap", hyphenate="true" but no luck. Could anyone please help with the same?[wrap_email](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jgj7Q.png)

```
                           <fo:block font-size="9pt" margin-bottom="12pt">
                             #if($!{email})
                             ${email.toUpperCase()}
                             #else
                             ${displayUid.toUpperCase()}
                             #end
                          </fo:block>
```

Comment: The question is tagged with both 'apache-fop' and 'antenna-house'. Are you using FOP or AH Formatter? AH Formatter has 'axf:word-break' (see https://www.antenna.co.jp/AHF/help/en/ahf-ext.html#axf.word-break) and 'axf:word-wrap' (see https://www.antenna.co.jp/AHF/help/en/ahf-ext.html#axf.word-wrap) extensions that could help but aren't available in FOP.

Comment: I am using FOP, in FOP do we have any tag to wrap the long text?

Comment: See these previous questions: * https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4350788/how-to-force-wrap-on-table-entries
* https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36810691/force-line-break-after-string-length

Comment: The proper way to do this is to insert zero-width break spaces at your *chosen* break points. Especially for email addresses. You need to avoid confusion with say an email that contains a "." .... what if the formatter broke that after the "." and the email was like Apache.Fop@apache.org. If the "Apache." is orphaned at the end of a line, the user may interpret as the end of a sentence and think the email is "Fop@apache.org"

Comment: I don't have any breakpoint, just want to wrap the long text within the cell. Which is going out of the defined cell.