# How to make fo:table-cell wrap text to a new line?

Tags: xml, xslt, xsl-fo

My generated .pdf file has a few cells in one row and I need text in each cell to wrap to a new line once cell runs out of space. I included fo:block wrap-option="wrap" for the .xsl file but it doesn't seem to work. This is a sample of what I have if anyone can tell me what I am doing wrong I would appreciate.

```
<fo:table-row>
                                        <fo:table-cell>
                                        <fo:block wrap-option="wrap">
                                            <xsl:value-of select="CUST_NUM1"/>
                                        </fo:block>
                                        </fo:table-cell>
                                        <fo:table-cell>
                                        <fo:block wrap-option="wrap">
                                            <xsl:value-of select="CUST_NUM2"/>
                                        </fo:block>
                                        </fo:table-cell>
                                        <fo:table-cell>
                                        <fo:block wrap-option="wrap">
                                            <xsl:value-of select="CUST_NUM3"/>
                                        </fo:block>
                                        </fo:table-cell>
</fo:table-row>
```

Comment: You do not show the actual data. I suspect that the values in CUST_NUM1 ... are very long and have no natural language breakpoints. Please post the data also for this in order to understand. If it is because you have very long lines that are not "words" with break points, you will need to implement a solution like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4350788/xsl-fo-force-wrap-on-table-entries