# Can we wrap the text to next line when it exceeds table cell length in XSL-FO?

Tags: xml, xsl-fo

I need to wrap the text to next line if it exceeds the length of the table cell in XSL-FO.

Sample XSL-FO:

```
    <fo:table-row>
       <fo:table-cell padding-bottom="3px" text-align="right" width="4cm" margin="0" margin-right="0.27cm">
        <fo:block-container>
            <fo:block >
                <fo:inline>Herewith: </fo:inline>
            </fo:block>
        </fo:block-container>
    </fo:table-cell>
    <fo:table-cell  padding-bottom="3px" text-align="left" width="7cm" margin="0" margin-left="-0.22cm">
        <fo:block-container>
            <fo:block>
                <fo:inline  font-family="FrutigerLTStd-Bold" font-weight="bold">
                    <xsl:value-of select="herewith"/>
                </fo:inline>                                                    
            </fo:block>
        </fo:block-container>
    </fo:table-cell>
```

Here if table cell value somethingxhsjdjfjkshkjkh" values exceeds, it will not wrap it into next line until we give some space between the values. I tried with wrap-option="wrap". But if there is a space in values only, then it will bring it to next line.

Can anyone help on this?

Comment: Which rendering engine are you using? FOP? Antenna House Formatter? Other? Did you have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4350788/xsl-fo-force-wrap-on-table-entries?

Comment: With the markup as currently shown, the `fo:block-container` and the first `fo:inline` are redundant.  If you move the `@font-family` and `@font-weight` to the containing `fo:block`, then the second `fo:inline` becomes redundant as well.  Setting `font-family="FrutigerLTStd-Bold"` and `font-weight="bold"` is also almost certainly redundant, both since "FrutigerLTStd-Bold" would be bold anyway and since your formatter should be able to find the bold variant if you instead had `font-family="FrutigerLTStd"` and `font-weight="bold"`.

Comment: This question is asked and answered at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4350788/xsl-fo-force-wrap-on-table-entries/4533760#4533760 as @potame has pointed out

Answer (score 0):

If your formatter supports hyphenation and the text is able to be hyphenated, then enabling hyphenation will help.

If it's allowed for you to change the column widths, then enabling automatic table layout (http://www.w3.org/TR/xsl11/#fo_table) may let the formatter squeeze the width of the other columns and increase the width of this column so that this text doesn't overflow.