# wrap-option="wrap" is not working for continuous text using fop

Tags: xsl-fo, apache-fop

I am using below code to generate pdf. But content was adjust to second line. Some text was crossed to pdf.

```
<fo:table-cell padding-left="5mm" padding-top="2mm">
   <fo:block font-size="10pt" text-align="justify"  wrap-option="wrap">
      Thisistextcharacterlengthissue.Needtofixtextwrapoverthecontentinthisline.Andalsotestspecialcharacters.
   </fo:block>
</fo:table-cell>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/4350788/4453460

Answer (score 1):

The text is your block has no spaces, so FOP finds no place where it can break it to form several lines.

Possible solutions:

- insert some spaces in the text, if possible
- set `hyphenate="true" language="en"`, either on the `fo:block` or on an ancestor element, to enable hyphenation of the text in the block (but this would add an hyphen `-` at the end of the broken lines)
- insert some *zero-width spaces* `&#x200B;` in the text; these characters have no visible effect, but they signal FOP (or any other formatter) a position where it can end a line if needed