# Long sentences without any white space in between flows into adjacent cells/block:

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0, xsl-fo

The Long sentences without whitespace in between as shown in Paragraph are not wrapped inside the table cell using XSLT
Could anyone suggest me a way to make long words to be wrapped?

Example:

```
   <text>
        <paragraph>This is my question 
        <br/>               
        <br/>  Long.Text.In.Access.web.apps,.the.Long.Text.field.can.store.up.to.2^30.1.bytes,.and.is.equivalent.to.the.SQL.Server.data.type.of.nvarchar(max)..If.you.want,.you.can.set.a.character.limit.to.prevent.your.users.from.using.the.full.capacity.of.the.field......Its.SQL.Server.equivalent.is.nvarchar,.with.length.from.1.to.4000. 
        </paragraph>
    </text>
```

Comment: While asking an XSLT question you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example): (1) Input XML. (2) Your logic, and XSLT that tried to implement it. (3) Desired output. (4) XSLT processor and its compliance with the XSLT standards: 1.0, 2.0, or 3.0.

Comment: What is the target format, HTML? Have you explored any settings of the target format to wrap words e.g. for HTML the relevant CSS settings like https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/word-break?

Comment: Yes I have tried using css codes like word-break ,   
    
        word-break: break-all;
        word-break: break-word;
Both I have tried.

The Target format is PDF , I have to display XML document in PDF using XSLT

Comment: You do not go from XML+XSL to PDF. You are normally going to XSL FO or HTML and formatting that to PDF. So the question needs to be tagged appropriately to provide you guidance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to force wrap on table entries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4350788/how-to-force-wrap-on-table-entries)