# how to wrap the long word (containing more than hundred characters) in XSL FO

Tags: xsl-fo

sorry for disturbance. I want to print a word "c_sunil_folder1_folder2_folder3_folder4_folder5_folder6_suniltext.pdf" in a table cell using XSL FO but the length of word is so long and also can contains more than hundred characters in a word so it is not wrapping in a single column

Could any one suggest a solution if it is possible to wrap with in a column

```
<fo:table-cell xsl:use-attribute-sets="table.cell" border-top="none" keep-together.within-line="always">
<fo:block keep-together.within-line="always">
<fo:inline><xsl:value-of select="'c_sunil_folder1_folder2_folder3_folder4_folder5_folder6_suniltext.pdf'"/>
</fo:inline>
</fo:block>
.
.
.
```

Output: In the output we can see that text is overlapping in next column of table:

[image: Text is overlapping in next column text]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then [edit] your question to include your source code as a working [mcve], which can be tested by others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing to do is remove the `keep-together.within-line="always"` that is keeping everything to one line.

The watermark on your screenshot suggests that you could be using Antenna House Formatter. If so, you can use `axf:word-break="break-all"` (see https://www.antenna.co.jp/AHF/help/en/ahf-ext.html#axf.word-break) to allow Antenna House Formatter to break anywhere within a word.

Otherwise, the usual technique is to use XSLT to insert a ZERO-WIDTH SPACE between every character in a table cell.  See [How to force wrap on table entries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4350788/how-to-force-wrap-on-table-entries/4533760#4533760)

Comment: thank you so much Tony for your kind attention and suggestion for this question, I used the 'Zero width space' code for this question and it is working. I would appreciate more if you will provide an active link of " https://www.antennahouse.com/product/ahf64/ahf-ext.html#axf.word-break"

Comment: Sorry, I had copied that from an older answer. The correct link is: https://www.antenna.co.jp/AHF/help/en/ahf-ext.html#axf.word-break