# Wrap within table-cell with long word in FOP

Tags: xslt, word-wrap, cells, apache-fop, xmltable

I have a table in FOP and it is working nicely until I get a very long word. The word then overwrites the cell ending in the table. I tried the wrap-option="wrap" within the table-cell and/or the block of the cell but it doesn't work

**`**Total Edit**`**

since I guess it is to complicated to just show bits here is the complete xsl file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<xsl:stylesheet version="1.1" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format" exclude-result-prefixes="fo">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" omit-xml-declaration="no" indent="yes" />
<xsl:param name="tableCell" select="'1.0'" />

<!-- Globale Variablen START -->

<xsl:param name="tabbgcolor" select="'#EEEEEE'" />



<!-- Globale Variablen ENDE -->

<xsl:template match="/datasheet">
    <fo:root xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format" xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions">
        <fo:layout-master-set>
            <fo:simple-page-master page-height="29.7cm" page-width="21cm" margin-top="1cm" margin-bottom="1cm" margin-left="1.5cm" margin-right="1.5cm" master-name="first">
                <fo:region-body margin-top="20mm" margin-bottom="20mm" />
                <fo:region-before extent="15mm" />
                <fo:region-after extent="15mcm" />
            </fo:simple-page-master>
            <fo:simple-page-master master-name="new" margin-right="1.0cm" margin-left="1.0cm" margin-bottom="1cm" margin-top="1cm" page-height="21cm" page-width="29.7cm">
                <fo:region-body margin-top="30mm" margin-bottom="20mm" />
                <fo:region-before extent="30mm" />
                <fo:region-after extent="15mm" />
            </fo:simple-page-master>
        </fo:layout-master-set>



        <fo:page-sequence language="de" country="DE" master-reference="new" initial-page-number="1">

            <fo:static-content flow-name="xsl-region-before">
                <fo:block text-align="center" font-size="12pt" padding="5pt" font-weight="bold">
                    <xsl:value-of select="title" />
                </fo:block>
                <fo:block text-align="right" font-size="12pt" padding="5pt" font-weight="bold">
                    <xsl:value-of select="date" />
                </fo:block>
                <fo:block text-align="right" font-size="12pt" padding="0pt" font-weight="bold">
                    <xsl:value-of select="time" />
                </fo:block>
                <fo:block>
                    <fo:leader leader-length="100%" leader-pattern="rule" rule-thickness="2pt" color="black" />
                </fo:block>
            </fo:static-content>

            <fo:static-content flow-name="xsl-region-after">
                <fo:block text-align="center">
                    Seite
                    <fo:page-number />
                    von
                    <fo:page-number-citation ref-id="TheVeryLastPage" />
                </fo:block>
            </fo:static-content>





            <fo:flow flow-name="xsl-region-body">



                <fo:block>
                    <fo:leader />
                </fo:block>
                <fo:block>
                    <fo:leader />
                </fo:block>
                <fo:block>
                    <fo:leader />
                </fo:block>


                <fo:block font-weight="bold" padding="5pt" padding-top="25pt">
                    Jahre <xsl:value-of select="fromYear" /> bis <xsl:value-of select="toYear" />
                </fo:block>

                <fo:block text-align="center">
                    <xsl:choose>
                        <xsl:when test="dataList != ''">
                            <fo:table table-layout="fixed" width="100%" border-style="solide" border-width="1pt">
                                <fo:table-column column-width="25%" border-style="solid" border-width="1pt" />
                                <fo:table-column column-width="25%" border-style="solid" border-width="1pt" />
                                <fo:table-column column-width="25%" border-style="solid" border-width="1pt" />
                                <fo:table-column column-width="25%" border-style="solid" border-width="1pt" />



                                <fo:table-header>
                                    <fo:table-row>
                                        <fo:table-cell border-style="solid" font-weight="bold" border-width="0pt">
                                            <fo:block>
                                                Cell1
                                            </fo:block>
                                        </fo:table-cell>
                                        <fo:table-cell border-style="solid" font-weight="bold" border-width="0pt">
                                            <fo:block>
                                                Cell2
                                            </fo:block>
                                        </fo:table-cell>
                                        <fo:table-cell border-style="solid" font-weight="bold" border-width="0pt">
                                            <fo:block>
                                                Cell3
                                            </fo:block>
                                        </fo:table-cell>
                                        <fo:table-cell border-style="solid" font-weight="bold" border-width="0pt">
                                            <fo:block>
                                                Cell4
                                            </fo:block>
                                        </fo:table-cell>

                                    </fo:table-row>
                                </fo:table-header>

                                <fo:table-body>
                                    <xsl:for-each select="dataList"> 
                                        <fo:table-row>
                                            <fo:table-cell padding="5pt" border-style="solid" border-width="1pt">
                                                <fo:block text-align="left">
                                                    <xsl:value-of select="data1" />
                                                </fo:block>
                                            </fo:table-cell>
                                            <fo:table-cell padding="5pt" border-style="solid" border-width="1pt">
                                                <fo:block text-align="left">
                                                    <xsl:value-of select="data2" />
                                                </fo:block>
                                            </fo:table-cell>
                                            <fo:table-cell padding="5pt" border-style="solid" border-width="1pt">
                                                <fo:block text-align="left">
                                                    <xsl:value-of select="data3" />
                                                </fo:block>
                                            </fo:table-cell>
                                            <fo:table-cell padding="5pt" border-style="solid" border-width="1pt">
                                                <fo:block text-align="left">
                                                    <xsl:call-template name="intersperse-with-zero-spaces">
<xsl:with-param name="str" select="data4"/>
</xsl:call-template>
                                                </fo:block>
                                            </fo:table-cell>

                                        </fo:table-row>
                                    </xsl:for-each>  
                                </fo:table-body>

                            </fo:table>
                        </xsl:when>
                        <xsl:otherwise>
                            <fo:block padding="6cm" text-align="center" font-weight="bold" font-size="16pt">No data.
                            </fo:block>
                        </xsl:otherwise>
                    </xsl:choose>
                </fo:block>


                <fo:block id="TheVeryLastPage">
                </fo:block>
            </fo:flow>
        </fo:page-sequence>

        <!-- ___________________________________________________________________________________________________________ -->





    </fo:root>

</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="intersperse-with-zero-spaces">
<xsl:param name="str"/>
<xsl:variable name="spacechars">
    &#x9;&#xA;
    &#x2000;&#x2001;&#x2002;&#x2003;&#x2004;&#x2005;
    &#x2006;&#x2007;&#x2008;&#x2009;&#x200A;&#x200B;
</xsl:variable>

<xsl:if test="string-length($str) &gt; 0">
    <xsl:variable name="c1" select="substring($str, 1, 1)"/>
    <xsl:variable name="c2" select="substring($str, 2, 1)"/>

    <xsl:value-of select="$c1"/>
    <xsl:if test="$c2 != '' and
        not(contains($spacechars, $c1) or
        contains($spacechars, $c2))">
        <xsl:text>&#x200B;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:if>

    <xsl:call-template name="intersperse-with-zero-spaces">
        <xsl:with-param name="str" select="substring($str, 2)"/>
    </xsl:call-template>
</xsl:if>
</xsl:template> 




</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The cell data4 is the one with the problems.... like 255 digits or characters at once with no hyphen oder space.

The input is from a database but could be like:

```
 <datasheet>
   <dataList>
     <data1>intro</data1>
     <data2>section</data2>
     <data3>cutters</data3>
     <data4>743576746876357467569384657654687465874638563465873487435767468763574675693846576546874658746385634658734874357674687635746756938465765468746587463856346587348743576746876357467569384657654687465874638563465873487435767468763574675693846576546874658746385634658734874357674687635746756938465765468746587463856346587348743576746876357467569384657654687465874638563465873487435767468763574675693846576546874658746385634658734874357674687635746756938465765468746587463856346587348743576746876357467569384657654687465874638563465873487435767468763574675693846576546874658746385634658734874357674687635746756938465765468746587463856346587348</data4>

   </dataList>
 </datasheet>
```

the result should be a table like:

```
|cell1  |cell2  |cell3  |cell4  |
_________________________________
|intro  |section|cutters|7435767|
                        |4687635|
                        |7467569|
                        |3846576|
_________________________________
```

and so on in cell 4

**Now the above works**

Comment: In order to help with your template that tries to intersperse zero-spaces, please show the `<xsl:template>` start tag (the beginning) of the template you already put in, and also the template named "intersperse-with-zero-spaces". Then it would be good to show sample input (at least one chunk with a long string), expect output (the FO), and actual output.

Comment: Thanks for posting the sample data and more of the stylesheet. There must be copy/paste errors in the stylesheet... there is an `<xsl:param>`, which is only supposed to occur at the beginning of a template, in the middle of the template. The stylesheet is therefore invalid. Are there supposed to be two templates? Also, I don't yet see the template named intersperse-with-zero-spaces; but maybe you're still adding it. Finally, what XSLT processor are you using - Xalan? XSLT 1.1 was an abandoned version.

Comment: the xsl param was C&P error removed that
I use the newes FOP bin

Comment: **THAT'S IT** you got the solution ... <xsl:template name="intersperse-with-zero-spaces"> needed to be added above the <xsl:param name="str"/> line the upper param needed to be deleted and the first template needed to be closed ... now it works (fixed it see above)

Comment: Good. I'm surprised your XSLT processor wasn't giving you an error. I'll put the "solution" part of my comment into my answer, so you can accept it (click the check mark). :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option would be for you to break up the long number/word in XSLT while you're transforming to FO. You'd have to decide where you want it to break.

See also: 
[XSL-FO fop. Long text flows into adjacent cells/block, obscuring stuff there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4252807/xsl-fo-fop-long-text-flows-into-adjacent-cells-block-obscuring-stuff-there)

## Update (copied from comment):

There must be copy/paste errors in the stylesheet... there is an `<xsl:param>`, which is only supposed to occur at the beginning of a template, in the middle of the template. The stylesheet is therefore invalid. Are there supposed to be two templates? Also, I don't yet see the template named `intersperse-with-zero-spaces`; but maybe you're still adding it.

## Update 2:

The above has been fixed in the Question.

I had assumed the second template couldn't be `intersperse-with-zero-spaces`, since it was calling that template. It didn't occur to me that it was supposed to be a recursive template!

By the way, if you have the option of using XSLT 2.0, the `intersperse-with-zero-spaces` template could be replaced by a much more efficient regexp replace.

Comment: I tried this but it doesn't work for me.
I am triying right now the zero width space approch but not very lucky.. see my edit above

Comment: The previous comment refers to the part of the answer above the first Update.

Answer (score 3):

```
<xsl:template name="intersperse-with-zero-spaces">
<xsl:param name="str"/>
<xsl:variable name="spacechars">
    &#x9;&#xA;
    &#x2000;&#x2001;&#x2002;&#x2003;&#x2004;&#x2005;
    &#x2006;&#x2007;&#x2008;&#x2009;&#x200A;&#x200B;
</xsl:variable>

<xsl:if test="string-length($str) &gt; 0">
    <xsl:variable name="c1" select="substring($str, 1, 1)"/>
    <xsl:variable name="c2" select="substring($str, 2, 1)"/>

    <xsl:value-of select="$c1"/>
    <xsl:if test="$c2 != '' and
        not(contains($spacechars, $c1) or
        contains($spacechars, $c2))">
        <xsl:text>&#x200B;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:if>

    <xsl:call-template name="intersperse-with-zero-spaces">
        <xsl:with-param name="str" select="substring($str, 2)"/>
    </xsl:call-template>
</xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

calling place use to call like below:

```
<fo:block text-align="left">
   <xsl:call-template name="intersperse-with-zero-spaces">
<xsl:with-param name="str" select="data4"/>
</xsl:call-template>
  </fo:block>
```

I tested, it's working fine.

Answer (score -1):

Add hyphenate="true", then it will automatically adjust the spaces in the table cell.

```
<fo:table-cell border-bottom-width="0px" border-left-width="0px" 
    border-right-width="0px" border-top-width="0px" font-size="9px" 
    padding-left="0px" border-style="solid" border-width="1pt" 
    border-color="white" padding-start="0px" padding-end="2px" 
    padding-before="0px" padding-after="0px" width="16%" display-align="center"
    text-align="start" hyphenate="true">
```

Comment: Hyphenation has nothing to do with "adjusting spaces", and it does not usually apply to a long numerical string as the one causing the problem.