# Wrapping a table in PDF using XSLT that exceeds the page size

Tags: xml, pdf, xslt-1.0, transformation, xsl-fo

I'm trying to fit a multi-column table based on an XML file in a standard A4 page. The problem is that the column that exceeds the margin doesn't appear in the generated file (as expected).  I want to make the outer columns appear in the next row, however I can't find any way how to do this. I tried to simply change the font size or the orientation of a page, but these solutions are simply a bypass that would fail when the number of columns were higher.
Is this even possible to do this using plain XSLT 1.0?
My code is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format" version="1.0">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <fo:root xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format">
        <fo:layout-master-set>
            <fo:simple-page-master master-name="A4" page-height="29cm" page-width="21cm"
                margin-bottom="2cm" margin-top="2cm" margin-left="1.5cm" margin-right="1.5cm">
                <fo:region-body margin-top="1cm"/>
                <fo:region-before extent="1.5cm"/>
                <fo:region-after extent="1.5cm"/>
            </fo:simple-page-master>
        </fo:layout-master-set>

        <fo:page-sequence master-reference="A4">


            <fo:static-content flow-name="xsl-region-before">
                <fo:block>Stylistique suppliers report. Generated <xsl:value-of
                        select="report/statistics/dateOfGeneration"/></fo:block>
            </fo:static-content>
            <fo:static-content flow-name="xsl-region-after">
                <fo:block>Page <fo:page-number/></fo:block>
            </fo:static-content>

            <fo:flow flow-name="xsl-region-body">
                <fo:block>
                    <fo:external-graphic src="logo.jpg" width="auto" height="auto"
                        content-height="300px"/>
                </fo:block>

                <fo:block linefeed-treatment="preserve">Summary table</fo:block>
                <fo:table>
                    <xsl:for-each select="report/suppliers/supplier">
                        <fo:table-column column-width="30mm"/>
                    </xsl:for-each>

                    <fo:table-header>
                        <fo:table-row>
                            <xsl:for-each select="report/suppliers/supplier">

                                <fo:table-cell>
                                    <fo:block font-weight="bold" width="30mm" font-size="8px">
                                        <xsl:value-of select="name"/>
                                    </fo:block>
                                </fo:table-cell>
                            </xsl:for-each>
                        </fo:table-row>
                    </fo:table-header>

                    <fo:table-body>

                        <fo:table-row>
                            <xsl:for-each select="report/suppliers/supplier">
                                <fo:table-cell>
                                    <xsl:for-each select="productList/product">
                                        <fo:block>
                                            <xsl:value-of select="name"/>
                                        </fo:block>
                                        <fo:block>
                                            <xsl:value-of select="priceInPLN"/>
                                        </fo:block>

                                    </xsl:for-each>
                                </fo:table-cell>

                            </xsl:for-each>
                        </fo:table-row>

                    </fo:table-body>
                </fo:table>

            </fo:flow>

        </fo:page-sequence>
    </fo:root>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: You should also provide the source XML file.

Comment: Is every column always 30mm?

Comment: @TonyGraham yes, the problem is that if the column size is equal to 30mm, some of the cell contents overlap each other, but if I increase the width, the remaining cells are cut from the document, so this is why I need to wrap the table.

Comment: Which formatter are you using?

Comment: @TonyGraham Apache FOP for FO, Saxon6.5.5 for XSLT

Answer (score 1):

Fake the table by using `fo:block` for the table rows and `fo:inline-container` (with a fixed width) for each table cell.

You may have trouble getting the 'cells' to have the same height, but what you want to do is out of scope for `fo:table`.

Alternatively, if you know exactly where the table should break, you could omit the `fo:table-row` and use the `starts-row` and `ends-row` properties on the `fo:table-cell` to cause your breaks.

---

Since you are using XSLT 1.0 and you know the width of the table cells, you could use Muenchian Grouping (https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=muenchian) to group the appropriate number of cells per row. (This would be *much* simpler if you were using XSLT 2.0 or XSLT 3.0 and could use `xsl:for-each-group`.)

Also, there's multiple answered SO questions about wrapping text in table cells, including:

- [XSL-FO: Force Wrap on Table Entries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4350788/xsl-fo-force-wrap-on-table-entries)
- [Wrap within table-cell with long word in FOP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17317588/wrap-within-table-cell-with-long-word-in-fop?noredirect=1&lq=1)

(Wrapping text would also be simpler if you were using XSLT 2.0 or XSLT 3.0 (or using AH Formatter, FWIW).  See, e.g., https://stackoverflow.com/a/33689540/4092205.)