# export to PDF table columns not wrapped

Tags: xsl-fo, apache-fop, docx4j

I created very simple test which contains table with 2 columns. One column contains long line without spaces and second columns small line. In doc I see that line from the first line is wrapped

And I convert this document to PDF using

- [Sample example](https://github.com/plutext/docx4j/blob/master/src/samples/docx4j/org/docx4j/samples/ConvertOutPDF.java)
- [service](http://webapp.docx4java.org/OnlineDemo/docx_to_pdf_fop.html)

Result is the same - line from first column is writed over second column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not a solution, but since this is an XSL FO / FOP issue, for insight into the issue, please see:

[XSL-FO: Force Wrap on Table Entries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4350788/xsl-fo-force-wrap-on-table-entries)

[XSL-FO fop. Long text flows into adjacent cells/block, obscuring stuff there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4252807/xsl-fo-fop-long-text-flows-into-adjacent-cells-block-obscuring-stuff-there)

Tracking at https://github.com/plutext/docx4j/issues/142

Answer (score 0):

The following isn't pretty, but it achieves wrapping, by inserting zero-width spaces after each character. If you wanted, you could insert them every `x` characters or use some other heuristic to choose better places to break.

```
String zeroWidthSpace = Character.toString((char) 8203);
textToInsert = textToInsert(("(.)"), "$1" + zeroWidthSpace);
td.getContent().add(mdp.createParagraphOfText(textToInsert));
```