# How to wrap continuous text of data?

Tags: xsl-fo, apache-fop

I am using Apache's FOP library to generate a PDF from an XML. I have a `<fo:block>` on which I am using a wrap-option="wrap". In the XML, if the field from which this block gets the value has any line breaks or whitespaces, it wraps the text. But, if there are no line breakers/whitespaces/tabs etc., it does not wrap.

How can I achieve wrapping such data that has no line-breakers/whitespaces/tabs?

Comment: Please show us an input XML and XSLT stylesheet that exhibit the problem: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve. Thanks.

Comment: Related questions: [highest rated question on this topic, no useful answer](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4252807/4453460), [question with an XSLT 1.0 template to insert *zero-width spaces*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17317588/4453460)

Answer (score 1):

The property `wrap-option="wrap"` does **not** force the processor to break the text into lines at certain positions, it just states
 (XSL-FO specifications, [§ 7.16.13 "wrap-option"](http://www.w3.org/TR/xsl/#wrap-option)):

> Line-breaking will occur if the line overflows the available block width

Note also that `"wrap"` is the default property value, so there is no need to explicitly set it, unless the inherited value would be `"no-wrap"`.

In order for the line breaking to actually build several lines, the text must have some **feasible break positions**: "regular" spaces, linefeeds, hyphenation points ...

If your field values have no spaces and you cannot enable hyphenation (for example because they are long numbers / alphanumeric strings) **you can add zero-width spaces** (`&#x200B;`) during the XSLT transformation: these characters constitute valid break positions, and are otherwise invisible.